# Google Sheet getValue() returns #N/A for cell containing Googlefinance() data

Tags: google-apps-script, google-sheets, google-finance, getvalue

I have a simple Google sheet retrieving Stock Data using **`=Googlefinance(ticker,"close",today()-7,today())`** in cell A2 (and the ajacent range). 
When I try to read the retrieved data in a script using `sheet.range("A2").getValue()` the script returns "`#N/A`" in cell A2 although it clearly has the word "Date" in it. All other values in the range return an empty value when retrieved through `sheet.getRange().getValue()`.  Is there any way to retrieve the `Googlefinance()` data with `getValue()`?

When I fill the range with values (paste as values) everything works well... it looks like `getValue()` cannot read `Googlefinance()` data.

```
function UpdateRange() {
var sheet=SpreadsheetApp.getActiveSpreadsheet().getSheetByName("Sheet1");
//cell A2 contains formula GOOGLEFINANCE("AAPL","close",today()-7,today())
var fTitle = sheet.getRange("A2").getValue();
//returned value is #N/A
var fDate = sheet.getRange("A3").getValue();
//returned value is an empty string
Logger.log(fTitle); 
Logger.log(fDate);
}
```

The `getValue()` statement should return the actual value of the cell, not `#N/A` or empty cells.

Answer (score 0):

When you specify a date range the result is not displayed in the formula cell.  Instead, it's displayed in the adjacent cells to the left and below.

[image]